# How to install JFrog Xray using other application user

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

1. How can we install JFrog Xray with our own application user instead of user and group xray on redhat standalone server?
2. xray and rabbitmq user and groups are created while installing JFrog Xray. But we need that to be owned and executed with our own user and group. How can we do that?
3. Why is it necessary to run the Jfrog Xray installation script under root or as sudo user?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer for all of them is the same: Your points are valid and the current situation is suboptimal. The `xray` user shouldn't be hardcoded for our microservices and root shouldn't be required for installing 3rd-party services, especially if the user installs those by themselves. We are working on fixing all that.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [jfrog-xray](/questions/tagged/jfrog-xray) and [artifactory](/questions/tagged/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>